# Facebook Graph API Insights returns empty array

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I cannot figure out how to get particular Facebook Insight metrics, and don't know if I am missing something, or doing something wrong, or there is a bug ... ?

I'm using JS SDK v2.0. After logging in, I have 4 granted permissions (`FB.api("/me/permissions" ...`): public_profile, email, read_insights, manage_pages.
Then, for the sake of an example, let's say I want to get page impressions of Lufthansa page. I tried:

`FB.api("/lufthansa/insights/page_impressions",...)`

`FB.api("/{lufthansa-page-id}/insights/page_impressions",...)`

`FB.api("/lufthansa/insights/page_impressions?period=day",...)`

`FB.api("/lufthansa/insights/page_impressions?period=day&since=1396310400&until=1399075200",...)`

None of these work. Or to be precise, all of those return empty array (`{data:Array[0],paging:Object}`). Can anybody help me out with tip what am I doing wrong? I also couldn't find any example online; there are many simple FB API examples, but none with working FB Insights API ...

Thank you,
Ales

Comment: I have been using the same thing for a project and was working until a few days/weeks ago when I notice missing data.  FB has obvious changed something in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that the problem is actually a documented bug.  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/665575443480429/